# How to use jetpack navigation with bottomNavigationView in android java

Tags: java, android, android-navigation

how can i use android jet pack with BottomnavigationView java it only Kotline code out there even on google docs i am confused

```
   navigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNavigationView,Navigation.findNavController(this,R.id.nav_host_fragment));
```

navigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNavigationView,Navigation.findNavController(this,R.id.nav_host_fragment));

onclick on the menu icon using navigate through the screen drawn from the navgraph

Answer (score 2):

You are doing it right. Just the id's of fragments in navigation graph xml file and the id's of menu items should be the same. So the navigation controller know which fragment to load.

```
val navController = findNavController(activity!!, R.id.bottomNavFragment)

val navHostFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.bottomNavFragment)!!

// set navigation graph
navController.setGraph(R.navigation.nav_graph_nav_bottom)
bottomNavigation.setupWithNavController(navController)
```

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin is essentially same thing with Java, if you still get confused, my project can help you a little bit, the best demo of Jetpack is the [**android-sunflower**](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-sunflower) - the official demonstration app of Android Jetpack, Although it is wrote in Kotlin, it can still implement by java.

In order to support Android Jetpack, I translated all kotlin implementations to Java, and added [app-java] module as the Java version of android-sunflower app, please check out [**android-sunflower-java**](https://github.com/hatewx/android-sunflower-java).

There are many UseCases of *Navigation*, *databinding*, *WorkManager*, *Room*, etc. I'm sure you will have a better understanding of *Navigation* component if you have a look at [**android-sunflower-java**](https://github.com/hatewx/android-sunflower-java) project.